# How to Compare Two Tables by value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to compare these tables. First compare by value and make the difference. Second if not exist so show not exist. If you see the image attached. In second table there is two persons with same info but different age, and in first table there is one person with same info like in second table. I need to show not exist in first table. I need result to look like image attached
[image]

```js
    const firstArr = [
        { partNo: '1',name: 'Per', age: '35'},
        { partNo: '3',name: 'Tom', age: '27'},
        {partNo: '6', name: 'Alex',age: '18'}
    ]
    const secondArr = [
        { partNo: '1', name: 'Per', age: '33'},
        { partNo: '3', name: 'Tom', age: '27'},
        { partNo: '6', name: 'Alex', age: '18'},
        { partNo: '6',  name: 'Alex', age: '22'}
    ]


let table1 = `<table><tr><th>PartNo</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>`
let table2 = `<table><tr><th>PartNo</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>`

for (let i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {   
for (let j = 0; j < secondArr.length; j++) {
    table1 += `<tr><td>${firstArr[i].partNo}</td><td>${firstArr[i].name}</td><td>${firstArr[i].age}</td></tr>`
    table2 +=  `<tr><td>${secondArr[j].partNo}</td><td>${secondArr[j].name}</td><td>${secondArr[j].age}</td></tr>`
}
}
table1 += `</table>`
table2 += `</table>`
document.getElementById('firstTable').innerHTML = table1
document.getElementById('secondTable').innerHTML = table2
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
<div id="firstTable"></div>
<div>''''''''</div>
<div id="secondTable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the comparison rules? There doesn't appear to be any unique values in the data shown (duplicates of name & partNo for example). Are you only concerned with array indexing?

Comment: compare values of cells. if name in first row not equal name in second row style this cell in red color. In this example the age of first name in first table not equal the age of first name in second table.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your loop for the second array is within the first one

---

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)  it will get less messy

```js
const firstArr = [{
    partNo: '1',
    name: 'Per',
    age: '35'
  },
  {
    partNo: '3',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: '27'
  },
  {
    partNo: '6',
    name: 'Alex',
    age: '18'
  }
]
const secondArr = [{
    partNo: '1',
    name: 'Per',
    age: '33'
  },
  {
    partNo: '3',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: '27'
  },
  {
    partNo: '6',
    name: 'Alex',
    age: '18'
  },
  {
    partNo: '6',
    name: 'Alex',
    age: '22'
  }
]


let table1 = `<table><tr><th>PartNo</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>`
let table2 = `<table><tr><th>PartNo</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>`

firstArr.forEach(element => table1 += `<tr><td>${element.partNo}</td><td>${element.name}</td><td>${element.age}</td></tr>`);

secondArr.forEach(element => table2 += `<tr><td>${element.partNo}</td><td>${element.name}</td><td>${element.age}</td></tr>`);

table1 += `</table>`
table2 += `</table>`
document.getElementById('firstTable').innerHTML = table1
document.getElementById('secondTable').innerHTML = table2
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div id="firstTable"></div>
  <div>''''''''</div>
  <div id="secondTable"></div>
</div>
```

---

Or if you still want to use a for loop you can simply get your loop out of the second one

```js
const firstArr = [{
    partNo: '1',
    name: 'Per',
    age: '35'
  },
  {
    partNo: '3',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: '27'
  },
  {
    partNo: '6',
    name: 'Alex',
    age: '18'
  }
]
const secondArr = [{
    partNo: '1',
    name: 'Per',
    age: '33'
  },
  {
    partNo: '3',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: '27'
  },
  {
    partNo: '6',
    name: 'Alex',
    age: '18'
  },
  {
    partNo: '6',
    name: 'Alex',
    age: '22'
  }
]


let table1 = `<table><tr><th>PartNo</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>`
let table2 = `<table><tr><th>PartNo</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>`

for (let i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
  table1 += `<tr><td>${firstArr[i].partNo}</td><td>${firstArr[i].name}</td><td>${firstArr[i].age}</td></tr>`

}
for (let j = 0; j < secondArr.length; j++) {
  table2 += `<tr><td>${secondArr[j].partNo}</td><td>${secondArr[j].name}</td><td>${secondArr[j].age}</td></tr>`
}


table1 += `</table>`
table2 += `</table>`
document.getElementById('firstTable').innerHTML = table1
document.getElementById('secondTable').innerHTML = table2
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div id="firstTable"></div>
  <div>''''''''</div>
  <div id="secondTable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can i compare these two tables? to be like the image i attached. If values not equal style it to red color. If row not exist write in other row not exist.